# vlookup and paste in App Script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Not sure if this is even possible, but would anyone know if theres a way of using app script to move cell data to a specified area. Sort of a reverse Vlookup?
I want it to send a cell's data to an area that matched the cell's title, in a similar way to how Vlookup will pull data from a cell that matches the title... But in reverse.

Thanks for any help you guys could give :)

Update:
Below is a link to a practice cell with no script
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ie8k6a9gcOg06tVVc1bCFhandIH7vy2LUgk2_vusOAc/edit?usp=sharing

The idea is that The cell containing £300 (D7) would be directed to B7 through the titles of their cells (both being 02/01/22)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. Thanks for the spreadsheet. You refer to "Worksheets" and this isn't a term used with Google Sheets. So, just to clarify...  do you have one spreadsheet file with two sheets, or two spreadsheet files?

Comment: Its two spreadsheet files. One file contains the source information, and the second is where this will be stored.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear why you would need to use a script, because this can be done with a plain vanilla `hlookup()` formula, like this:

`=arrayformula( iferror( hlookup(A6:A15, D6:F7, rows(D6:F7), false) ) )`

See the new [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ie8k6a9gcOg06tVVc1bCFhandIH7vy2LUgk2_vusOAc/edit#gid=360772667) sheet in your sample spreadsheet. To read the data from another spreadsheet file, use an `importrange()` in place of `D6:F7` and `2` in place of `rows(D6:F7)`.

To answer your question, you can read the data from another spreadsheet file with `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` and do the lookup with `Array.indexOf()` like this:

```
function transverseLookup() {
  const sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp
    .openById('1ie8k6a9gcOg06tVVc1bCFhandIH7vy2LUgk2_vusOAc')
    .getRange('Sheet1!D6:F7');
  const targetRange = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActive()
    .getRange('Sheet1!A6:B15');
  const sourceKeys = sourceRange
    .offset(0, 0, 1)
    .getDisplayValues().flat();
  const sourceValues = sourceRange
    .offset(1, 0, 1)
    .getValues().flat();
  const values = targetRange.getDisplayValues()
    .map(row => row[0])
    .map(key => [sourceValues[sourceKeys.indexOf(key)] ?? null]);
  targetRange.offset(0, 1, values.length, values[0].length)
    .setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Hey, I know that it's possible using formulas, but I was wondering if it was possible in app script

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: The reason id like it to be a script is due to the original data thats being moved, is changing each week. I have a system that receives the data, but wanted a script to automatically filter this into a separate area based on where the data is from.
Sounds complicated, but its sorta like getting a box of fruit, and needing it separated into whats apples and whats pears :)

Comment: The `hlookup()` formula will do that automatically as the data gets updated. To do it with a script, set the `transverseLookup()` function to run on a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)